# Swapping finite product with infinite sum

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, analytic-number-theory

I have from my analytic number theory notes that states $$\prod_{p\le P} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{p^{ks}} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{c_P(n)}{n^s}$$ for  primes $p$ and $Re(s)>1$. $c_P(n)$ is $1$ if all prime factors of $n$ is $\le P$ and $0$ otherwise.

This seems to be obtained throught swapping the finite product with the infinite sum. I think this is a general result that holds for absolutely convergent series but  I can't find any proof for it. I would greatly appreciate if anyone could provide me insight into why this holds and how we can represent the rearranged infinite sum.

Comment: The condition $Re(s)>1$ gives you absolute convergence.

Comment: Note that $c_P(xy)=c_P(x)c_P(y)$ and $\prod_{p} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{c_P(p^k)}{p^{ks}}=\prod_{p\le P} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{p^{ks}}$